# FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification never triggers when the computer hosting the shared printer is restarted

Tags: python, windows, winapi, printing, pywin32

I work on a software designed, among other things, to detect and manage print jobs from a Windows workstation. The printers are all configured on a specific computer, and then shared with all workstations through regular Windows printer sharing. My issue is that the function `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification` is never triggered, once the remote computer (e.g., the one hosting the printers) is restarted.

Here is the code relevant to the problem:

```
from ctypes import byref, PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS, PPRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_GC, PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_TYPE, JOB_NOTIFY_TYPE, wintypes
import win32con, win32event, win32gui, win32print, win32ui
winspool = ctypes.WinDLL('winspool.drv', use_last_error=True)

JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_PRINTER_NAME        = 0x00
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME        = 0x01
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_PORT_NAME           = 0x02
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_USER_NAME           = 0x03
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_NOTIFY_NAME         = 0x04
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DATATYPE            = 0x05
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_PRINT_PROCESSOR     = 0x06
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_PARAMETERS          = 0x07
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DRIVER_NAME         = 0x08
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DEVMODE             = 0x09
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_STATUS              = 0x0A
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_STATUS_STRING       = 0x0B
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR = 0x0C # not supported
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DOCUMENT            = 0x0D
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_PRIORITY            = 0x0E
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_POSITION            = 0x0F
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_SUBMITTED           = 0x10
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_START_TIME          = 0x11
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_UNTIL_TIME          = 0x12
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_TIME                = 0x13
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_TOTAL_PAGES         = 0x14
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_PAGES_PRINTED       = 0x15
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_TOTAL_BYTES         = 0x16
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_BYTES_PRINTED       = 0x17
JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_REMOTE_JOB_ID       = 0x18


PRINTER_CHANGE_ADD_JOB = 0x00000100
DEFAULT_FIELDS = (
    JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_PRINTER_NAME,
    JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_STATUS,
    JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DOCUMENT,
    JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_TOTAL_PAGES,
    JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DEVMODE)

def pause_and_get_print_job_info(self, printer_name: str=None, timeout: float=-1):
    EVENEMENT_IMPRIMANTE = win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0
    EVENEMENT_DECONNEXION = win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1
    RESULTAT_VIDE = { "print_job_id": -1 }
    RESULTAT_DECONNEXION = { "print_job_id": -9999 }

    if (timeout != -1):
        timeout = int(timeout * 1000)

    hPrinter = wintypes.HANDLE()
    change_detected = wintypes.DWORD()
    fields = (wintypes.WORD * len(DEFAULT_FIELDS))(*DEFAULT_FIELDS)
    opt = PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS(pTypes=PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_TYPE(Type=JOB_NOTIFY_TYPE, pFields=fields))
    pinfo = PPRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_GC() # note: GC subclass
    result = RESULTAT_VIDE
    winspool.OpenPrinterW(printer_name, byref(hPrinter), None)

    try:
        hChange = winspool.FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification(hPrinter, PRINTER_CHANGE_ADD_JOB, 0, byref(opt))

        try:
            # The result will be WAIT_OBJECT_0 if the printer triggered the event, WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1 if the event comes from session closure.
            event_result = win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects([hChange, self._shutdown_event], False, win32event.INFINITE)

            ###### The thread never reaches this point. WaitForMultipleObjects is stuck waiting, until a shutdown / disconnect occurs. #####
            
            # This means there was an error.
            if event_result not in (EVENEMENT_IMPRIMANTE, EVENEMENT_DECONNEXION):
                return RESULTAT_VIDE
            # The Shutdown / Disconnect event was triggered.
            elif event_result == EVENEMENT_DECONNEXION:
                return RESULTAT_DECONNEXION

            winspool.FindNextPrinterChangeNotification(hChange, byref(change_detected), None, byref(pinfo))
            
            # [...] The rest of the Windows print job processing follows.
```

As you can see, we use `WaitForMultipleObjects` in order to account for either a new print job, using `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification`, or a Windows shutdown / logoff event.

To be clear, this works very well, **until the remote computer sharing the printers is restarted**. After this happens, the `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification` is never triggered, until the workstation or our software is also restarted.

Following another question here, I have tried adding an exception in the Windows Firewall of all workstations, to add File and Print Sharing to the allowed protocols. I have also tried to use only the `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification` in conjunction with `WaitForSingleObject`, to no avail.

My theory is that the handle tied to the printer, used in the `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification` function call, changes once the remote computer restarts and the connection to the remote printer through Windows is reinitialized. This means that when a new print job is created, the event is not triggered, because it is never linked to the old printer handle. However I have no clue how to solve or circumvent this issue, if that is event really what it is.

Comment: According to the Doc:[FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/findfirstprinterchangenotification)

Callers of FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification must ensure that the printer handle passed into FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification remains valid until FindClosePrinterChangeNotification is called. If the printer handle is closed before the printer change notification handle, further notifications will fail to be delivered.

Comment: Yes, but how can I prevent the printer handle from being closed when the remote computer is restarted? Or how can I detect that the printer handle changed?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there is no way to printer handle from being closed when the remote computer is restarted. You just could try to call `FindClosePrinterChangeNotification function` before restart the remote computer. The printer handle is created by calling the `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification function`.

Comment: My problem is that I have no control over when the remote computer is restarted. Therefore, I cannot choose to call `FindClosePrinterChangeNotification` at the appropriate time. Is there a way I could detect when a printer handle becomes invalid?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there is no way to detect when a printer handle becomes invalid. The handle is created by calling the FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification function. In my opinion, when the remote computer is restarted, the printer handle is invalid.

Comment: So it's a catch-22. I cannot close and recreate the printer handle until I know it has become invalid. But I cannot detect when it is invalid so I cannot know when to recreate it.

Comment: After the remote computer restarted, the printer handle is invalid. You have no control over when the remote computer is restarted, so there is no way to detect when a printer handle becomes invalid.